# django rest framework post method not allowed

Tags: http, post, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am creating an api and no idea why post method not allowed on any url.

views

```
class MessagesView(APIView):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = MessageSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

chat.urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("<str:pk>/", ChatDetail.as_view()),
    path("messages/", MessagesView.as_view()),
]
```

response

```
{
    "detail": "Method \"POST\" not allowed."
}
```

I am providing the token for the request, so `isAuthenticated` does not do anything wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first pattern will fire if you visit `messages/`. Indeed, its `<str:pk>` parameter matches any *string* (with at least one character and without slashes). But `messages` is thus also matched with this view.

What you can do is swap the places of the two urls, then calling `messages/` will fire the correct view:

```
urlpatterns = [
    #       ↓ messages first
    path('messages/', MessagesView.as_view()),
    path('<str:pk>/', ChatDetail.as_view()),
]
```

If `pk` is an integer, you can further restrict the `pk` with the `<int:…>` path converter:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('messages/', MessagesView.as_view()),
    path('<int:pk>/', ChatDetail.as_view()),
]
```